# Why do I get rego_unsafe_var_error in the rego playground trying to follow the rego documentation?

Tags: opa, rego

I am at the Variables section of the documentation ( https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-language/#variables) trying to make `q[x]` work in the rego playground - https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/IrSisS4LMf.

But all I get is **1 error occurred: policy.rego:18: rego_unsafe_var_error: var x is unsafe**

Here is the rego code:

```
package test

import future.keywords.in
import future.keywords.if
import future.keywords.contains

sites := [
    {"name": "prod"},
    {"name": "smoke1"},
    {"name": "dev"}
]

q contains name if {
    some site in sites
    name := site.name
}

q[x]
```

I do not understand what am I doing different from the documentation.

What am I missing?